# understanding json data

Tags: json

Hello fellow programmers. I got an URL and im supposed to fetch JSON data which is hosted on that URL. As im totally new to JSON i only can recognize some of the data but there's some "weird" characters in the JSON data that i'd like to know about. I used an online "JSON viewer" to see the data from URL i got and it looks like this:

```
{
    "Content": "\u000d\u000a\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u0009Current Leaders\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u0009Sales in 000's\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u0009Alice\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u00091,000\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u0009Bill\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u0009975\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u0009Curt\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u0009967\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u0009Deborah\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u0009965\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u0009Elsa\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u0009\u0009964\u000d\u000a\u0009\u0009\u000d\u000a\u0009\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a\u0009 \u000d\u000a",
    "DateChanged": "\/Date(1330709756123+0100)\/",
    "InfoContentID": 150,
    "Topic": "INCENTIVE LEADER BOARD"
  }
```

The question is, what are all those `u000d\u0009` What doest that mean? It's all weird. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i believe the characters you are seeing are unicode

Comment: That's Unicode and a lot of those characters you have are control chars such as carriage return, line feed and tab.

Comment: Then if that's unicode i am so screwed because im supposed to to get that data and show it in one of my blackberry application. I dont know if i have to use WebServices to get the data. Obviously it's not JSON because as far as i know JSON URLs end with .json. Any ideas on what technology to use to get the data? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Those are unicode characters `\u000d` is the carriage return character (`\r`), `\u000a` is new line (`\n`), `\u0009` is the tab character (`\t`). Basically it's all whitespace.